# Django Integer Field being read as undefined by Angular

Tags: django, angularjs

I have a model in Django with the following two variables for an Event model:

```
notification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
priority_int = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)  # low priority
```

I get the data from the user using a controller called new-event.controller.js, and then I call create() in events.service.js like this:

```
Events.create(notification, priority_int).then(createEventSuccessFn, createEventErrorFn);
```

new-event.controller.js also broadcasts the following:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event.created', {
            notification: notification,
            priority_int: priority_int,
            author: {
                username: Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount().username
            }
        });
```

My data is being saved correctly in the database, using the angular factory defined in events.service.js - factory is named Events

```
function create(notification, priority_int){
    return $http.post('/api/v1/events/', {
            notification: notification,
            priority_int: priority_int
        });}
```

I have an account.controller.js that is injected with Events and $scope, account.controller.js catches the broadcast with:

```
$scope.$on('event.created', function (event, pud) {
            Events.get(username).then(eventsSuccessFn, eventsErrorFn);
        });

function eventsSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('event success: ');
            vm.events = data.data;  //already correctly instantiated
        }
```

I have an events.directive.js, which has the controller events.controller.js. Inside events.controller.js, I am watching for the changes to vm.events with:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
            return $scope.events;
        }, render);
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $(window).width();
        }, render);
```

This is the render function inside events.controller.js:

```
function render(current, original) {}
```

current refers to the array of events. Inside the render function, for created events and newly created events, if I retrieve each one's notification value, I receive the correct boolean value (the value that was entered by the user and saved in the database). But if I try to retrieve the priority_int value for any event, I get undefined, despite the database saving the user-inputted value correctly.

I'm incredibly confused. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my events.service.js:

```
 (function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.events.services')
    .factory('Events', Events);

Events.$inject = ['$http'];

/**
 * @namespace Events
 * @returns {Factory}
 */
function Events($http) {
    var Events = {
        all: all,
        create: create,
        get: get
    };

    return Events;
//functions all, create and get below
```

Here is my events.directive.js:

```
(function () {
'   use strict';

 angular
.module('app.events.directives')
.directive('events', events);

 /**
  * @namespace events
  */
 function events() {
  console.log('in events directive');
/**
 * @name directive
 * @desc The directive to be returned
 * @memberOf app.events.directives.Events
 */
var directive = {
  controller: 'EventsController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    events: '='
  },
  templateUrl: '/static/templates/events/events.html'
};

return directive;
 }
  })();
```

Comment: How is your `Events` class / constructor defined?

Comment: The arguments your `Events.create` function accepts don't seem to match up with the arguments you're passing it.

Comment: @AndrewMagee for conciseness of the post I removed the other variables I was passing, this issue seems to only happen for integer values, retrieval of character fields and boolean fields work fine

Comment: Ok then. Well what does your `Events.get` function look like? Is it making an HTTP request? I would put some logs there and see if it's getting the values you want it to get.

Comment: Yes, it is a HTTP request, I will check the logs.